# OpenVPN Client Connected to Server - Is it possible for client to take incoming connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I have a rather odd request.

We have an Amazon VPC that is the primary network that my company controls.

I have a client running a physical computer on a separate network in another part of the country. We do not control that physical network, so at this time I cannot install a site2site VPN over there for this project alone.

That remote client computer is running OpenVPN Client and connecting successfully into our VPC.

However, here is the problem, I need to send packets **to** the client since it's running a hardware dongle that (obviously) cannot run in AWS since it's hardware. It's essentially running a single service that needs to be talked to but I cannot initiate a connection into a client.

I do realize that Amazon has direct connect and VPN services to connect a physical LAN to a VPC, however that isn't really possible in the scope of this project.

I can easily create a new VPN server in the VPC if that's a requirement

OpenVPN's **client-to-client** is the closes thing I can see, but that routes within the VPN server, so I don't think that will help because the machine initiating the request isn't a client of OpenVPN, it just sits on our VPC.

One thing to note is that the connection to this machine is only lightweight traffic, no heavy bandwidth is needed.

Is there some sort of tunnel that I can create? We would have to jump through some serious hoops in order to get the Gateway/Firewalls/Routers reconfigured at the remote site so that is an absolute last resort.

EDIT:
I wanted to add this for clarity: 
https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21783

The image on that page pretty much sums up what I need to do, however the PC on the right side isn't connected via OpenVPN, it's already on the same LAN/subnet as the OpenVPN server.

Comment: `Is it possible for client to take incoming connection?` - **Yes**.  Just setup your your routing, and firewalling correctly.  Since you didn't include any details about how your network was actually setup, I can't help you much beyond that.

Comment: @Zoredache is right, vpn is just a tunnel. Network-wise your client can be handled like any other client/server in your network assuming correct firewall and routing configuration.

Comment: Alright I'll see if I can work with the routing and see if I can get it to accept the connection. Thank you. I'll report back so @Zoredache can get credit on an answer